# Webpack4 in 2021 : compiling the evm decompiler Nodejs package without getting lots of compile error because webpack5 became available

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-4, fedora-33

I’m new Nodejs and [just wanted to use a version with bugfix with no compiled JavaScript in that case](https://github.com/dafky2000/evm) but didn’t want to perform any kind of TypeScript compiling/maintenance.
After running npm install using the latest version of node 10 lts, I tried to run `npm run build` and it failed :

```
example@WINDOWS81:~/sources/app/Ethereum/util/evm$ npm run build

> evm@0.2.0 build
> npm run build:hashes && webpack


> evm@0.2.0 build:hashes
> ts-node ./scripts/build.ts

Updated hashes successfully
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.2.2 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from /home/example/sources/app/Ethereum/util/evm/tsconfig.json
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.2.2 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from /home/example/sources/app/Ethereum/util/evm/tsconfig.json
ℹ ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
✖ ｢atl｣: Checking finished with 51 errors
ℹ ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
✖ ｢atl｣: Checking finished with 51 errors
Hash: 24ef6388777595a8177fadf1b598fef18405ab1d
Version: webpack 4.28.3
Child
    Hash: 24ef6388777595a8177f
    Time: 14999ms
    Built at: 2021-09-14 7:28:30 PM
                                              Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
              ../typings/src/classes/evm.class.d.ts  951 bytes          [emitted]
            ../typings/src/classes/stack.class.d.ts  232 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/classes/tx.class.d.ts  513 bytes          [emitted]
                          ../typings/src/index.d.ts  266 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/add.d.ts  404 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/addmod.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                ../typings/src/opcodes/address.d.ts  342 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/and.d.ts  404 bytes          [emitted]
                ../typings/src/opcodes/balance.d.ts  381 bytes          [emitted]
              ../typings/src/opcodes/blockhash.d.ts  386 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/byte.d.ts  415 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/call.d.ts  648 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/callcode.d.ts  652 bytes          [emitted]
           ../typings/src/opcodes/calldatacopy.d.ts  445 bytes          [emitted]
           ../typings/src/opcodes/calldataload.d.ts  422 bytes          [emitted]
           ../typings/src/opcodes/calldatasize.d.ts  347 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/caller.d.ts  341 bytes          [emitted]
              ../typings/src/opcodes/callvalue.d.ts  344 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/codecopy.d.ts  441 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/codesize.d.ts  343 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/coinbase.d.ts  343 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/create.d.ts  476 bytes          [emitted]
                ../typings/src/opcodes/create2.d.ts  477 bytes          [emitted]
           ../typings/src/opcodes/delegatecall.d.ts  619 bytes          [emitted]
             ../typings/src/opcodes/difficulty.d.ts  345 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/div.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/dup.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                     ../typings/src/opcodes/eq.d.ts  604 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/exp.d.ts  404 bytes          [emitted]
            ../typings/src/opcodes/extcodecopy.d.ts  485 bytes          [emitted]
            ../typings/src/opcodes/extcodehash.d.ts  385 bytes          [emitted]
            ../typings/src/opcodes/extcodesize.d.ts  385 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/gas.d.ts  338 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/gaslimit.d.ts  343 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/gasprice.d.ts  343 bytes          [emitted]
                     ../typings/src/opcodes/gt.d.ts  453 bytes          [emitted]
                ../typings/src/opcodes/invalid.d.ts  379 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/iszero.d.ts  374 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/jump.d.ts  424 bytes          [emitted]
               ../typings/src/opcodes/jumpdest.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                  ../typings/src/opcodes/jumpi.d.ts   1.29 KiB          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/log.d.ts  551 bytes          [emitted]
                     ../typings/src/opcodes/lt.d.ts  453 bytes          [emitted]
                  ../typings/src/opcodes/mload.d.ts  381 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/mod.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
                  ../typings/src/opcodes/msize.d.ts  340 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/mstore.d.ts  417 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/mul.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/mulmod.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/not.d.ts  371 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/number.d.ts  341 bytes          [emitted]
                     ../typings/src/opcodes/or.d.ts  407 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/origin.d.ts  341 bytes          [emitted]
                     ../typings/src/opcodes/pc.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/pop.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/push.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/return.d.ts  480 bytes          [emitted]
         ../typings/src/opcodes/returndatacopy.d.ts  465 bytes          [emitted]
         ../typings/src/opcodes/returndatasize.d.ts  349 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/revert.d.ts  480 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/sar.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
            ../typings/src/opcodes/selfbalance.d.ts  342 bytes          [emitted]
           ../typings/src/opcodes/selfdestruct.d.ts  386 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/sha3.d.ts  478 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/shl.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/shr.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
             ../typings/src/opcodes/signextend.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
                  ../typings/src/opcodes/sload.d.ts  804 bytes          [emitted]
                 ../typings/src/opcodes/sstore.d.ts  879 bytes          [emitted]
             ../typings/src/opcodes/staticcall.d.ts  617 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/stop.d.ts  339 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/sub.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
                   ../typings/src/opcodes/swap.d.ts  180 bytes          [emitted]
              ../typings/src/opcodes/timestamp.d.ts  344 bytes          [emitted]
                    ../typings/src/opcodes/xor.d.ts  408 bytes          [emitted]
                      ../typings/src/utils/hex.d.ts  220 bytes          [emitted]
                  ../typings/src/utils/opcodes.d.ts   17.5 KiB          [emitted]
                ../typings/src/utils/stringify.d.ts   69 bytes          [emitted]
          ../typings/src/utils/stringifyEvents.d.ts   97 bytes          [emitted]
       ../typings/src/utils/stringifyFunctions.d.ts  106 bytes          [emitted]
    ../typings/src/utils/stringifyInstructions.d.ts  138 bytes          [emitted]
        ../typings/src/utils/stringifyMappings.d.ts   76 bytes          [emitted]
         ../typings/src/utils/stringifyStructs.d.ts   76 bytes          [emitted]
       ../typings/src/utils/stringifyVariables.d.ts   77 bytes          [emitted]
                                             EVM.js   21.7 MiB     EVM  [emitted]  EVM
                                         EVM.js.map    349 KiB     EVM  [emitted]  EVM
                cc19a96b6d3e3405869a01466a6a081c.js   5.84 KiB          [emitted]
    Entrypoint EVM = EVM.js EVM.js.map
    [./data/eventHashes.json] 2.01 MiB {EVM} [built]
    [./data/events.json] 772 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./data/functionHashes.json] 9.34 MiB {EVM} [built]
    [./data/functions.json] 6.89 MiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/classes/evm.class.ts] 4.86 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/classes/stack.class.ts] 1.44 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/classes/tx.class.ts] 3.55 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/index.ts] 626 bytes {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/opcodes.ts] 7.15 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyEvents.ts] 941 bytes {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyFunctions.ts] 1.26 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyInstructions.ts] 1.73 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyMappings.ts] 1.8 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyStructs.ts] 468 bytes {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyVariables.ts] 816 bytes {EVM} [built]
        + 81 hidden modules

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/tapable/tapable.d.ts:67:63
        TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:24:10
        TS2305: Module '"../../tapable/tapable"' has no exported member 'Tapable'.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:775:23
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:776:22
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:777:28
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:778:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:779:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:780:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:781:27
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:782:21
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:783:30
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:784:24
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:792:28
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:793:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:794:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:795:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:815:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:816:19
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:818:40
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:819:35
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:820:43
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:823:23
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:825:35
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:826:30
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:827:38
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:842:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:861:25
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:862:24
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:868:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:869:40
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:870:32
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:875:31
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:881:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:882:24
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:890:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:891:28
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:895:43
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:896:38
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:897:46
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:914:22
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:915:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:916:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:917:22
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:918:19
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:988:25
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:990:29
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1006:25
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1007:26
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1008:31
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1011:26
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1076:24
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.
Child
    Hash: adf1b598fef18405ab1d
    Time: 20835ms
    Built at: 2021-09-14 7:28:36 PM
                                  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                            EVM.node.js  21.6 MiB     EVM  [emitted]  EVM
                        EVM.node.js.map   283 KiB     EVM  [emitted]  EVM
    cc19a96b6d3e3405869a01466a6a081c.js  5.84 KiB          [emitted]
    Entrypoint EVM = EVM.node.js EVM.node.js.map
    [./data/eventHashes.json] 2.01 MiB {EVM} [built]
    [./data/events.json] 772 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./data/functionHashes.json] 9.34 MiB {EVM} [built]
    [./data/functions.json] 6.89 MiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/classes/evm.class.ts] 4.86 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/classes/stack.class.ts] 1.44 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/classes/tx.class.ts] 3.55 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/index.ts] 626 bytes {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/opcodes.ts] 7.15 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyEvents.ts] 941 bytes {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyFunctions.ts] 1.26 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyInstructions.ts] 1.73 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyMappings.ts] 1.8 KiB {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyStructs.ts] 468 bytes {EVM} [built]
    [./src/utils/stringifyVariables.ts] 816 bytes {EVM} [built]
        + 76 hidden modules

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/tapable/tapable.d.ts:67:63
        TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:24:10
        TS2305: Module '"../../tapable/tapable"' has no exported member 'Tapable'.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:775:23
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:776:22
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:777:28
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:778:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:779:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:780:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:781:27
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:782:21
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:783:30
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:784:24
        TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:792:28
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:793:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:794:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:795:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:815:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:816:19
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:818:40
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:819:35
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:820:43
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:823:23
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:825:35
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:826:30
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:827:38
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:842:27
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:861:25
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:862:24
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:868:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:869:40
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:870:32
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:875:31
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:881:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:882:24
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:890:33
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:891:28
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:895:43
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:896:38
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:897:46
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:914:22
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:915:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:916:21
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:917:22
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:918:19
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:988:25
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:990:29
        TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1006:25
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1007:26
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1011:26
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

    ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1076:24
        TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.
example@WINDOWS81:~/sources/app/Ethereum/util/evm$
```

According to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12185, this is because webpack5 is now **available that others could compile it before but that this is no longer possible to do it in 2021 without changing the build scripts**.
I tried to add `"skipLibCheck": true` to `tsconfig.json` but then the webpack generated file does no longer works because it generate lots of imports to non compiled typescript files/dependencies.

I don’t understand what I should do. Is there a way to compile https://github.com/dafky2000/evm without changing the build scripts or the code as it worked before ?